# Spool Oracle - Header in a single line

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I'm trying to run a query through unix via sqlplus command and spool the output to a file. My table has more than 30 columns and it want them to be printed as below.

```
col1|col2|col3|col4|col5|........
a   |b   | c  |d   |f   |........
```

What I've used.

```
        set colsep '|' 
        set trimspool on
        set termout off
        set echo off
        set trim on
        set heading on
        set feedback off
        set linesize 32000
        set trimout on
        set pagesize 50000
        set underline off
```

The output I'm getting is the columns are getting word wrapped. Can someone help?

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/54149/how-to-make-sqlplus-output-appear-in-one-line

Comment: Although honestly I tried your settings on a table with 317 columns and it's not wrapping. Are you sure it isn't an issue with your text file viewer?